# How do I tell Netbeans that a section of code is Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, netbeans

I'm using the Zend Framework's javascript helpers of the form:

```
<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>
//Javascript here
<?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd(); ?>

//Rest of view here
```

The problem is that Netbeans keeps complaining about code problems in the block, because it thinks it's an HTML, rather than a Javascript, block. Plus syntax coloring is broken.

Netbeans already has special comment hinting which you can use to apply a type to a variable when it can't be resolved by Netbeans automatically to tell it that we're writing Javascript in that range, rather than HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?php  $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>
//<script type="text/javascript">
var validJSsyntax = true,
    netbeansJShighlighting = true,
    problem = 'solved';
//</script>
<?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd(); ?>
```

Of course it will produce two useless lines in your JS output, but you can modify `captureEnd()` method to strip those for you.

Comment: // is used for comments and which is incorrect syntax for HTML

Comment: It is used in comment in case it would appear in `<script>` block (to be valid js syntax and do not throw any errors), in HTML it is just a textNode and NetBeans does not alert about using textNode inside `<head>` block, so it works just as OP wanted.

Comment: +1 for good answer, wish I could +1 again for hilarious code snippet.

Comment: Checkmarked + bountied because this is more readable than Tushar's answer. Both are good answers though.

Answer (score 4):

From my knowledge this functionality is not yet implemented in the current version of NetBeans IDE that is 6.9.1.  I can show you a workaround through which you can fool the NetBeans IDE to highlight the Javascript as a script section, and also keeps the PHP processor happy.  It will look like following code snippet:

```
    <?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>
    <?php if( false ) {?><script><?php } ?>
        // keep Javascript here
    <?php if( false ) { ?></script><?php } ?>
    <?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd(); ?>
```

I have tested this in NetBeans IDE 6.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I was actually just reading about this yesterday in [their blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/formatting_php_and_html):

Their HTML in PHP parsing has been flaky, especially with indenting incorrectly short/alternate form code, but the latest [nightly builds](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) (I presume those after 201010060000) have improvements in that area. I haven't tried it yet but give it a shot.

Comment: This is about how PHP tags are handled in general -- it doesn't tell Netbeans anything about Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

print problematic code with PHP

```
<script <?PHP echo 'type="text/template"?> id="Template-1">
    //your code here
</script>
```

If you print all script tag with PHP, NetBeans perfectlly format HTML tags

Comment: If NetBeans thinks that's an appropriate solution, I'd scrap it now.