# Is possible in NETBEANS to highlight a file as a different language (not extension-related)?

Tags: php, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

In Notepad++ I can set the language highlighting to be different from what the program detects based on file extension. I'm wondering that if similar can be achieved in Netbeans. I have a .php file that has js code inside and I want that file to be highlighted based on js rules, not on php-rules.
Is it possible to change this for a single file, somehow?

Comment: If this is for JS - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4072050/258674

Comment: @dev-null-dweller something is wrong; it doesn't render the js file in the output (i don't get it in client). Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed !**
thanks *@dev-null-dweller* for giving me a starting point.
all I had to do was to add this lines:

```
<?php if ( false ){ ?><script><?php } ?>

//...js code in here

<?php if ( false ){ ?></script><?php } ?>
```

This fools netbeans to highlight the text as JS, but it won't really do anything because of the `if(false)`statement.